# MiKTeX (x64) on WIndows 8 Qt Error

Tags: miktex

I recently installed MiKTeX (x64) on WIndows 8 and fully upgraded it. In multiple occasions, such as invoking xetex, it prompts an error

```
Qt: Untested Windows version 6.2 detected!
```

Also the GUI of Texworks and auto-install dialog all revert back to old style theme.

What is this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Regarding the close vote: though it seems to be off-topic, it happens during a MiKTeX installation, so this question and answer may help fellow MiKTeX users who don't know how to deal with a Qt error, so I would leave it open to get a good answer, even if it refers to another site with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it seems to be related to the Qt framework that could be not yet compatible with the new windows (6.2). You could:

- Check the [forum for Qt](http://qt-project.org/forums/) for compatibility issues
- Try to upgrade your Qt version (nightly build or RC...)
- Downgrade to windows 7

If Qt were compatible with windows 8, you should fill a bug report to MikTeX mainteners

Edit: [it seems to be not compatible,](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6751) as microsoft does not release information before releasing windows 8... So you have to wait or to downgrade your windows version

Comment: So TeXLive does not use Qt? It works perfectly.

Comment: OK, I checked the About of Texworks in TeXLive and MiKTeX. The former uses Qt 4.8 while the latter uses Qt 4.7.

Comment: It's likely the cause of your error; I invite you to fill a bug report (if there isn't already one) and contact the maintainer of MikTeX. The 4.7 version of Qt is rather old and I doubt that the modification to support win8 will be backported.

Comment: @KarsusRen I don't have win8, so I can't check, but try to replace the 5 `Qtxxxx.dll` in the folder `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` by the new one (from the 4.8 branch of Qt). It should work (on Linux, when we update such a library, we don't have to recompile the software that use it...)

Comment: Where can I file a bug report?

Comment: Probably here: http://miktex.org/email

Comment: I filed it two days ago, and apparently Christian Schenk fixed it today.

Comment: I have a similar trouble with Windows 10,