# Unable to install a missing package on-the-fly in MikTeX, 64 bit from WinEdt

Tags: miktex

It's strange but I am unable to compile beamer class documents under Windows 10. The following example

```
\documentclass[
    unicode,xcolor={dvipsnames,usenames}
]{beamer}
\typein{0=======================}
```

aborts compilation at `\documentclass` so that `\typein` macro is not reached. I see only the following message:

```
Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
```

Other documents are compiled with success as usually. I tested both PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX engines. I have the most recent version of MikTeX. MiKTex binaries were updated on 15th of June.

**Update:** There is a similar trouble with Windows 8.1, see [MiKTeX (x64) on WIndows 8 Qt Error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85792/miktex-x64-on-windows-8-qt-error?rq=1)

**Update 2**: As follows from the dialog below with Ulrike Fischer, the problem is caused by recent (2015-06-24) updates of MiKTeX binaries. This is quite typical case for MiKTeX: its updates too often destroys working systems.

Comment: I have no problems with windows 10 here.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Are you running MiKTeX with all recent updates? MiKTex binaries were updated on 15th of June.

Comment: I always have up-to-date TeX ;-). Yes I updated yesterday.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L3n6b.png

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't have windows 10 yet. Beside this: Run the package manager (admin), synchronize (menu repositories) and then check if there are new, uninstalled packages starting with miktex and install them. Then run the update manager (admin). In case that you are using texworks: Compile once on the command line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have no troubles under Windows 7 and the most recent updates installed on all my computers.

Comment: Did you check if there a **new** packages? Running the update manager is not enough! See critical updates here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490#108490

Comment: @HarishKumar: Do you have 32 or 64-bit version of MikTeX? I have 64-bit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: my  troubles might come from `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\Qt5Core.dll`. It contains the words "Untested Windows version %d.%d detected!" and is issued on 09.04.2015. Could you look at the date of `Qt5Core.dll` on your computers? `Qt5Core.dll` came to me in `miktex-qt5-bin-x64` archive packaged on 2015-06-24.

Comment: I have a 32bit miktex but the dates for the dll are the same. If I should guess I would say that your beamer document is trying to trigger the on-the-fly-dialog for some missing package and that this fails. Test it with some small document which loads a  package that you haven't yet. If you get the same error message make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, that quess sems to be partially true. Adding a package which is not yet installed aborts compilation from inside WinEdt. Although, few days ago (i.e. before I updated miktex binaries) the on-the-fly-dialog worked fine. However the trouble exists only if I run miktex from WinEdt. If I run miktex from command line, the on-the-fly-dialog works fine.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov: Error happens. Make a bug report. In the meantime you can deactivate on-the-fly and when you get errors install missing packages with the package manager.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Christian would hardly accept this bug report if the problem persist only from inside WinEdt.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov: I would try it anyway. Perhaps he knows what's going on. You could also try e.g. with texstudio (not texworks as this is broken currently anyway) to check if only winedt is affected. And you could set a message to the winedt list.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov I have 32 bit.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I've just updated MiKTeX on my Windows 7 x64
machine and got same problem: compilation aborts if a package is
missed and on-the-fly installation of missing packages in MiKTeX
Options is chosen. I've sent the error report in the mailing lists
of MiKTeX and WinEdt, however I wrote that the problem persists
only under Windows 10.

Comment: I can confirm the problem with the winedt console and that's imho something winedt must repair - texstudio and texworks seems to work fine for me. So it looks as it this time it wasn't miktex.